# Recover Project Code From Play Store

Tags: android, google-play

Recently I factory reset my computer, and reinstalled Android Studio. However, I forgot to save a copy of my project, and I can't find the code, even though it's already released into Google Play. Is there a way to recover the project code from the Play Store?

Comment: You could decompile the apk and try your luck. Next time use version control.

Comment: Where would I find the apk? And how would I decompile it?

Comment: The APK exists installed on your device, but you need root (I think) to get at it.

Comment: If you published a signed APK of obfuscated code (which you should), then it's highly unlikely you'll be able to fully reconstruct your source code. For obvious reasons that you could follow this process for any app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you may recover your code but i can't guarantee if you will be fully able to recover.

Just download your app from playstore.Then Install any Apk decode to decode your code.

Method 1: By Android Mobile

If your phone is rooted :
Use Showjava :https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.njlabs.showjava

Method 2:From online decoder 
Example: http://www.javadecompilers.com/apk

They plenty of decoder available just search "**apk to source code**"

Method 3 use apktool and dex2jar

follow these tutuorilas
    http://blog.inyourbits.com/2012/11/extending-existing-android-applications.html
    http://blog.inyourbits.com/2012/12/extending-existing-android-applications.html

Comment: Good luck - as the other folks have said, this will only get you back your decompiled Java files, and won't be an importable project file (just wanted you to be aware of that).  At the end of this, you won't be able to import this project into Android Studio, and be like it was before.

Comment: This worked for me. Unfortunately, the project wasn't the same as it was before and I'll have to start from scratch. Thanks for your help!